# Exposing internal private cluster nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

So I have a private Kubernetes cluster hosted on GKE inside of a Cloud VPC network, essentially the same as discussed in [Cloud NAT GKE example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example).

Thats all working, and now I've setup an Nginx ingress inside the cluster, with setting the annotation:

```
annotations:
  cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

This seems to work, as it eventually provisions an internal IP address within the VPC subnet range.

QUESTION:

How do I forward incoming traffic from the Cloud NAT gateway to that internal IP of the Nginx LoadBalancer service?

I want to have both ingress and egress happen on the same IP (so I don't have to expose the LoadBalancer service externally) that is linked to the Cloud NAT, if thats possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) enable instances in a private subnet to connect to the internet, but not other way around:

> Cloud NAT implements **outbound** NAT in conjunction with a default route
>   to allow your instances to reach the Internet. It does **NOT** implement
>   **inbound** NAT. Hosts outside of your VPC network can **only respond** to
>   established connections initiated by your instances; they **cannot**
>   initiate their own, new connections to your instances via NAT.

In a word, you can not NAT incoming traffic with cloud NAT gateway.